# Answer being auto-edited before being posted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

Not really much to say, other than here's a GIF to explain:

[image: Explanatory GIF]

Whilst in this example I'm editing an existing post, this happens for new posts too.

If I omit the `,` in the text, it removes the entire line.

What's going on?

<sup>Link to actual post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116710/37797</sup>

---

A text explanation:

1. Posted the following content:

   > Either reboot, or run
   >
   > ```
   > sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
   > ```
2. Submitted as

   > or run
   >
   > ```
   > sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
   > ```

Comment: Try reloading the page again? That's happened to me. Something that happens after the AJAX call to post the answer, and the text of the post doesn't update.

Comment: @daviesgeek Nope, reloading hasn't helped — just tried it again on that post (now one day later). Exact same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it was a false positive in the method that removes greetings from the beginning of the post. I see you've already found a workaround for this issue.

Anyway, fix is rolling out with build rev `2014.1.13.1297`.

Comment: Why remove the greetings, is there more information on this feature?

Comment: You can read more about it in [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)